# Automatically Facebook Debug Posts on Publish

Tags: facebook

I am looking to do something similar to this plugin which adds an "FB-Debugger" link on the admin of pages/posts: http://xlino.com/projects/facebook-debug-link-wordpress-plugin/

However, I'd like to make this even more automated by sending the post url directly to the Facebook Debugger on publish or re-publish by opening the debugger in a new browser tab with the results for the url.  This seems pretty possible because the url that would be passed to the debugger looks like

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=mysite.com/my-post

I guess my question is how can I automatically open up a new tab with:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=[**post-url**]

a second or two after the post is published or changed (there would need to be time delay for FB to find the post) ?

I know a little PHP and it seems like a pretty simple command, but what core WP file would I edit? Im using WP 3.3.1 . I've done some frontend template tweaking but nothing that changes or adds on to the admin.

Thanks!

Comment: oh, this is a plugin I wrote, few years ago ;-) There's now an extra button in Facebook's *debugger* to re-scrape the meta data (clear the cache). So it doesn't auto-scrape, like it used to do, where your idea would have been possible.